# add columns in awk from two files

Tags: join, awk

I have two files like shown below which are tab-delimited:

file A

```
chr1   123 aa b c d
chr1   234 a  b c d
chr1   345 aa b c d
chr1   456 a  b c d
....
```

file B

```
chr1   123    aa    c    d    e   ff
chr1   345    aa    e    f    g   gg
chr1   123    aa    c    d    e   hh
chr1   567    aa    z    c    a   ii
chr1   345    bb    x    q    r   kk
chr1   789    df    f    g    s   ff
chr1   345    sh    d    t    g   ll

...
```

I want to add a new column to file A from file B based on 2 key columns "chr1", "123" i.e.(first two columns are key columns). If the key columns matches in both files, the data in column 7 in file B should be added to column 3 in file A.

For example (chr1 123) key is found twice in file B, therefore 3rd column in file A has ff and hh separated by comma. If the key is not found it should put NA and output should look like as shown below:
output:

```
chr1   123  ff,hh       aa    b    c    d   
chr1   234    NA        a     b    c    d
chr1   345  gg,kk,ll    aa   b    c    d
chr1   456    NA        a    b    c     d
```

I usually do it in R but it takes huge amount of time for large datasets. Could someone provide an awk solution to speed up the task?

Comment: Yes, we can, but first show your attempts please

Comment: well, i am a newbie to awk where i can do little file processing kind of things but not any real code. I do it in R using collapse function and have no idea in awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this awk line:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=a[$1FS$2]?a[$1FS$2]","$7:$7;next}
{$3=(($1FS$2 in a)?a[$1FS$2]:"NA")FS $3}7' fileB fileA
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to add one more column with the above code. We added only column 7, likewise could we add one more column say column 5 along with column 7?  I played around with the code but couldn't manage to do this. Thanks in advance